# Wieferich prime numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I need help with an assigment I'm working on. the task is to write a program to find all Wieferich prime numbers between two given values. The equation to determine if it is a Wieferich prime is this:
  a Wieferich prime number p is such that p<sup>2</sup> divides 2<sup>(p − 1)</sup> − 1

This is what I have so far:

```
start=int(input("enter start value"))
end=int(input("enter end value"))

for c in range(start,end):
  if c%2!=0:
    primedet=(c**2)/((2**(c-1))-1)

    if primedet%1==0:
      print(c," is a Wiefrich Prime")
```

Every time I run it, it just prints all the odd numbers between the given values. I know that there are only two Wieferich prime numbers: 1093 and 3011. I really just not sure how to make this work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect `primedet%1` to do?

Answer (score 0):

The use of modular arithmetic make this a more easy task, because you want that 2<sup>p-1</sup> -1 be divisible by p<sup>2</sup>, that is 2<sup>p-1</sup> -1 = 0 (*mod* p<sup>2</sup>) rearrange this you get 2<sup>p-1</sup> = 1 (*mod* p<sup>2</sup>) in python this is

```
(2**(p-1)) % (p**2) == 1
```

but that is inefficient because first calculate 2<sup>p-1</sup> to then take the modulo, but don't worry, python have a efficient way of doing modular exponentiation with the 3 argument call of pow

```
pow(2,p-1,p**2) == 1
```

finally you also need that p be a prime, then with implementing a primality test you are ready to go

```
def isPrime(n:int) -> bool:
    return True #put here the code for primality check

def find_Wieferich_prime_in(star,end) -> [int]:
    resul = list()
    for p in range(star,end):
        if isPrime(p) and pow(2,p-1,p**2)==1:
            resul.append(p)
    return resul

print(find_Wieferich_prime_in(0,4000))
```

and that is everything that you need to find the [Wieferich prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime)

Your other mistake is in here

```
primedet=(c**2)/((2**(c-1))-1)
```

2<sup>c-1</sup>-1 is always bigger that c<sup>2</sup> (to a sufficient large c ) so the division c<sup>2</sup>/(2<sup>c-1</sup>-1) < 1

furthermore

```
primedet%1
```

because *primedet* is a float, when you do float%1 it give you the decimal part of that number, mix round issues and you will get too many zeros,
but more than that, what you are testing there is something that is not the definition of a Wieferich prime.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Based on your statement, the numbers have the property of being prime **prime** and **Wieferich** just by the means of the equation you gave, so (2<sup>(p - 1)</sup> - 1) % p<sup>2</sup> == 0 returns `True` means you found a number. As explained by @Copperfield, this can be written as (2<sup>(p-1)</sup>) % p<sup>2</sup> == 1. Then you can do (with the help of [pow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) which is faster):

```
# I assume we have `start` and `end` given by user. Now we can safely
# start from the first odd number greater or equal to start so we can
# stride by 2 in the `range` call which will half our iteration
start = start + 1 if start % 2 == 0 else start
# next I'm using filter because it's faster then the normal `for` loop
# and gives us exactly what we need, that is the list of numbers
# that pass the equation test. Note I've also included the `end`
# number. If I were to write `range(start, end, 2)` we wouldn't
# test for `end`
restult = list(filter(lambda n: pow(2, n - 1, n*n) == 1, range(start, end + 2, 2)))
```